# Bentley Project Wise for Data Retriaval

Tags: python, database, projectwise

This is my first post on stack.

I'm looking to gather a large amount of data from a multitude of files on PW so I can quantify a few things about the records.

The directories I'm working with have unique numbers and offer files that are all similar to files in other folders.

Is there a library from python I can use or any other useful tips for taking on this task?
It could potentially save many hours of work if I can do this with code.

A pseudocode example may look like.

for element in dataField:
search(folder)
if folder found:
search(file)

```
   if file found

      extract certain data from file X

      extractedData.append(data)
```

Thank you,
R

Comment: That looks like a good start towards some working code. Check out the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) module for some useful functions.

Comment: MattDMo, Thanks for the reply. I'll check it out but it would be nice if there was an API allowing direct linkage to my PW database.

Answer (score 0):

Based off a quick web search for `projectwise api`, there is a [web-based REST API available](https://ctdot-ws.projectwiseonline.com/ws/Pages/documentation/index.html), so you'll definitely want to look into that more. You'll need to read the docs carefully to figure out which endpoint does what, but once you know what information you need to send and what kind of data you'll receive, programming a basic Python interface shouldn't be too difficult. One may already exist, I didn't look too hard.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll give the docstring a look through.